# The highest even number in a array

Tags: java, arrays, max

I want the highest **even number** in the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[]{10, 46, 78, 32, 3, 80, 92, 11, 39, 57};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

    int largest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int number : a) {
        if(number > largest) {
            largest = number;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(largest);
}
```

The output is:

```
[10, 46, 78, 32, 3, 80, 92, 11, 39, 57]
2147483647
```

Comment: replace `int largest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` with int `largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;`

Comment: [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max) Check this function `Collections.max()`.

Comment: How? ...........

Comment: @CatarinaMota [Java Doc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection))

Comment: Note that OP wants the highest **even** number (odd numbers not allowed).

Comment: @Zabuza the question has been edited. The original question was as followed: "The highest number in a array - JAVA
I search about this and in my code this doesn't work. I want the highest number in the array."

Answer (score 2):

Don't init `largest` to max int:

```
int largest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Set it to min int instead

```
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Or, as @Stultuske suggests, initialize to the first value in the array:

```
int largest = a[0];
```

And as @Zabusa points out, you want even number. So improve the if statement so it only triggers on even numbers:

```
if (number > largest && number % 2 == 0) {
```

Comment: better yet, to the first element of the array.

Comment: @CatarinaMota no, it isn't.

Comment: @CatarinaMota You need to use the worst possible *largest value* as an initial guess. Otherwise your elements will always be smaller, and thus your initial guess is the biggest element. That's why we start by guessing `MIN_VALUE` as largest element. Since the elements of the array can then only get larger. Just play the algorithm on paper for a small example like `{1, 2}` and you see why that makes sense.

Comment: @Stefan Note that OP actually wants *"highest **even** number"*. Your answer (if used on OPs algorithm) only finds the largest number, possibly odd.

Comment: Note that using the first element as initial guess does now not work anymore in general. Since if that element is odd, the output would be that element in case all elements are odd. Maybe something like `-1` would be a better indicator for that case where `maxEven` does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

Your code has **two problems**. The first is, as others have already pointed out, that you start with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as initial guess, which is the wrong logic.

You need to use the worst possible *largest value* as an initial guess. Otherwise your elements will always be smaller, and thus your initial guess is the biggest element. That's why we start by guessing `MIN_VALUE` as largest element. Since the elements of the array can then only get larger. Just play the algorithm on paper for a small example like `{1, 2}` and you see why that makes sense.

The second problem is that you are actually considering **all values**, but you only wanted to consider the **even values**. We easily fix that by **skipping** all **odd values**.

---

### Code

Here is your code with both fixes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[]{10, 46, 78, 32, 3, 80, 92, 11, 39, 57};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

    // Start with lowest value as initial guess
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int number : a) {
        // Skip number if odd
        if (number % 2 == 1) {
            continue;
        }

        // Now we only consider and collect even numbers
        if (number > largest) {
            // Update the current guess
            largest = number;
        }
    }
    // We now considered all elements, the guess is
    // final and correct.
    // And also even since we skipped odd values.
    System.out.println(largest);
}
```

---

### Notes

If the array does not contain any even number, then the output will be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, you might consider this special case and catch it with some `if` clause.

Others suggest using an element of the array as initial guess. Since you only want even values, you may only consider using **even values** of the array for this initial guess. Otherwise, if the array does not contain even values, you would output an odd number again.

You could use a general and compact `Stream` solution as alternative to a custom method:

```
int maxEven = Arrays.stream(a)
    .filter(a -> a % 2 == 0) // Only even values
    .max()  // OptionalInt
    .orElse(-1); // Gets the value or uses -1 if not present
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative and simple solution using Streams:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 10, 46, 78, 32, 3, 80, 92, 11, 39, 57 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

int largest = Arrays.stream(a).filter((i) -> i % 2 == 0).max().getAsInt();


System.out.println(largest);
```

An efficient and quick approach. Should there be no even number in the list the `getAsInt()` will throw an `NoSuchElementException` which can be easily caught and handled in any way you like.

Instead of `getAsInt()` you could also use a `orElse(-1)` or similar if you do not want to work with an exception but want to have a defined value that signals that your input was probably malformed.

Comment: I like the `Stream` solution, but please consider using other methods when working with `Optional` objects, like `.orElse(-1)` for example. The `get` methods are usually discouraged and the designers even thought about deprecating them.

Comment: While I generally agree with you I did use `getAsInt()` exactly for the way it works by throwing an `NoSuchElementException` if the Optional is not present.
You could also use `orElse` obviously if you want. I will edit it in.

Comment: Yeah, but that's a bad habit if you don't immediately catch the exception. Since you then still have a `RuntimeException` that might get never discovered if no branch in project testing phase hits it. And then you have an undiscovered bug inside the project that may crash the App after release. That defeats the purpose of `Optional`, you could just use `null` with `NullPointerException`. That's why they discourage the use of `get` and instead suggest to always try one of the other methods. Since otherwise `Optional` would not offer any benefit compared to the old approach.

Comment: I certainly get where you are coming from and agree with you. For this minimal example it's imho totally fine to do it this way but encouraging bad habits is probably not a good thing to do.

Comment: Yeah, it's fine here. Just wanted to leave it as note :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Java 8 and higher, I'd definitely check out the [Streams API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). You can see your array of integer as a stream of values. With that stream, you can access high level functions such as min, max and filter. There are many advantages to using Streams in Java such as the one mentioned below.

> The Java 8 Streams can be seen as lazily constructed Collections, where the values are computed when user demands for it. Actual Collections behave absolutely opposite to it and they are set of eagerly computed values (no matter if the user demands for a particular value or not).

You can continue reading [here](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-java-8-streams-1)

So, to answer your initial question on how to retrieve your highest value in your array, here's how you could do it :

// snippet of only calculating the max

```
int maxValue = Arrays.stream(arrayOfVals)
  .mapToInt(v -> v)
  .filter(val -> val%2 == 0)
  .max()
  .orElse(-1);
```

Comment: I like the `Stream` solution, but please consider using other methods when working with `Optional` objects, like `.orElse(-1)` for example. The `get` methods are usually discouraged and the designers even thought about deprecating them. Also note that OP wants to collect only **even** numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Work For Both Positive and negative  **even number**

```
    int[] a = new int[]{100, 45, 77, 33, 3, 81, 80, 8, 120, 100,-2};
    int maxvalue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int anA : a) {
        if (anA % 2 == 0) {
            if (anA >= maxvalue)
                maxvalue = anA;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want the highest even number?

Comment: i have updated the answer it will give you the highest even number

Comment: So what if the list is `int[] a = new int[] {-10, -2};`?

Comment: What Ben wants to say is that your initial guess of `maxValue = 0` may be larger than all even elements in the array. In that case the output would be wrong and show `0` instead of `-2` for `{-10, -2}`. So you would need to adjust your initial guess, it must be `<=` the lowest possible `maxEven` result, otherwise `maxEven` won't be found.

Comment: thnx @Zabuza your comment help me :) for understanding the problem

Comment: Mh. `-2` will only work for this special input. If I try your code with `{-10, -8}` it will yield `-2` instead of `-8`. The only possibility is to either extract one even number from the array or to just use the lowest possible number in Java `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. In any case, you would need to additionally handle the special case where `maxEven` does not exist due to no even numbers like in `{1, 3}`.

Comment: @Zabuza i need a suggestion that the code i have written is good or bad because i am student and still learning to write better code

Comment: Your two `if` cases inside the `if (even)` are actually equivalent, they both do exactly the same. Sine the condition `a <= b` is the same as `b >= a`. So you may drop that and just write `maxvalue = anA`. Then your code is absolutely fine. Just the issue with the special case of `a` not containing any even numbers, but OP didn't specify what he wants in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    int [] arr = {31,-2,3,-4,9,3,8,11,7};
    int maxEven, firstEven = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
       if(arr [i]%2 == 0)
        {
            firstEven = arr [i];
            break;
        }
    maxEven = firstEven;
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
        if (arr [j]%2 == 0 && arr [j]>maxEven)
           maxEven = arr [j];
    if (maxEven == 1)
       System.out.println ("No even numbers in this array!");
    else
       System.out.println ("The maximum even number is: "+maxEven);
  }
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of why you think this is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different approach to this problem by using ternary operator.
Although I know, nested ternary operators are bad for performance. We can use simple If/Else conditions as well there.
A little experiment never hurts. Just never stop learning new things in your Life.

My working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numArray = {1, 121, 9, -1024, -30001, 5, 41, 181, 91};
    System.out.println("Max Even No is :: "+getMaxEvenNum(numArray));
}

public static int getMaxEvenNum(int[] numArray) {
    int maxNo = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i< numArray.length; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j< numArray.length; j++) {
            int maxOf2 = numArray[i]>numArray[j] ? (numArray[i]%2 == 0 ? numArray[i] : maxNo) : (numArray[j]%2 == 0 ? numArray[j] : maxNo);
            maxNo = maxNo>maxOf2 ? maxNo : maxOf2;
        }
    }
    return maxNo;
}
```

It will give the following output:

```
Max Even No is :: -1024
```

If no even number is present, then it will give the lowest integer value.

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way (if you are indeed using such small arrays) there is:
step 1. sort the array
step 2. print the last element.

For larger arrays, the solution provided by Stefan is indeed the better option.

Comment: That would be O(n log n)

Comment: Maybe simple. But potentially very expensive. The loop in the question is O(n) which no sort algorithm can match.

Comment: since the question is about the array at hand (containing 10 elements) the 'expense' is minimal.

Comment: You are right. But it would be better if you include such notes in your answer. Otherwise, especially a beginner, might think that this is a clever idea **in general**, which it is not. It was already said, `max` is in `Theta(n)` whereas *comparison based sorting* is in `Theta(n log n)`.

Comment: @Stultuske Note that OP actually wants *"highest **even** number"*. Your answer (if used on OPs algorithm) only finds the largest number, possibly odd.

Comment: @Zabuza yes, but that part was added after everyone answered.